# Span asp-validation-for is not consistant?

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-core

In asp-net-core, why does the span element with a valid asp-validate-for, behave inconsistently when its next to different types of elements. For example, take the following code.

```
    <div>
        <select asp-for="Floor">
            <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Floor"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input asp-for="Size (which is input type="text")" /><span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Size"></span>
    </div>
```

When both are missing validation, the select error message starts further away than the input type="text".
Cant find anything online. Anyone can help?

EDIT
Problem solved if the wrapped div element has css property `display:flex`.
But still curious why it happens and anyway of taking more control over it.

Comment: For the usage of `display:flex`, you can refer to here:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @YongqingYu Cant see it explain the usage of  dispaly:flex with span asp-validation for, so not quite sure your point.

Comment: Actually,I didn't reproduce your issue. For `display:flex` , it is used to provide maximum flexibility for box models:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp, for `span asp-validation for`, it's the bootstrap style here:https://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-bootstrap-style-validation-in-aspnet-core/